# bad comment behavior in cmake files

Tags: neovim, indentation, comments, visual-block, filetype-cmake

When I'm editing a cmake file in (neo)vim  I'm getting bad behavior block inserting comment characters.

Given this section of text

```
    install_license_file(
        PACKAGE tomcrypt
        TARGET tomcrypt::tomcrypt
        VERSION "1.18"
        TYPE "PD"
        FILE "/usr/share/doc/libtomcrypt1/copyright"
    )
```

If I put the cursor at the start of `install_license_file` and then do this sequence

1. `ctrl-v`
2. `6j`
3. `I`
4. `#`

I end up with this

```
 #install_license_file(
        PACKAGE tomcrypt
        TARGET tomcrypt::tomcrypt
        VERSION "1.18"
        TYPE "PD"
        FILE "/usr/share/doc/libtomcrypt1/copyright"
    )
```

but I'm trying to get this

```
   #install_license_file(
   #    PACKAGE tomcrypt
   #    TARGET tomcrypt::tomcrypt
   #    VERSION "1.18"
   #    TYPE "PD"
   #    FILE "/usr/share/doc/libtomcrypt1/copyright"
   #)
```

What's causing the unexpected behavior?

** UPDATE **

- if I completely clear out my `init.vim` and the system level `sysinit.vim` (Arch Linux) it works as expected but then if I do `set shiftwidth=2` I get the bad behavior.
- if I start with `nvim -u NONE` I get the expected behavior even after `set shiftwidth=2`

Comment: `What's causing the unexpected behavior?` probably a bad configuration, see [how do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: Check output of `:verbose xmap I` to see if you have a mapping for `I` in visual mode that might be affecting this behavior? Since removing `init.vim` doesn't seem to solve it by itself, then it's probably some plug-in or package that you installed or that was shipped with your Vim?

Comment: @filbranden It says no mapping for `I`. Note that this set of keystrokes works fine if I take the same file and rename to `file.py` instead of `file.cmake` (or even just do `set filetype=python`)

Comment: @ryan0270 Then maybe `:verbose imap #`? I'm trying to figure out which part specifically is causing the issue, it looks like a mapping is what would do that, so maybe it's one for inserting the `#`? Yeah it's definitely something associated with the filetype...

Comment: I don't think it's a mapping; even after clearing all mappings (`impac`,`vmapc`,etc) I still get the same bad behavior

Comment: @ryan0270 Yeah now that I actually tried it I managed to reproduce it on stock Vim! What you need is `:setlocal indentkeys-=0#`, I'll write an answer with more details on why this happens, why you need this and where you should add it. (Sorry I kept pushing to check the mappings etc. when it was actually an easily reproducible problem!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reproduce this behavior in stock Vim with no extra plug-ins.

The reason why this issue happens is that [`'indentkeys'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27indentkeys%27) includes `0#`, which triggers automatic reindentation of a line when you type `#` as the first character of the line.

(Note that this is mostly meant for the C/C++ language, for directives such as `#define` or `#include` which are meant to appear on the first column even when they appear in the middle of an indented block.)

It appears that the change in indentation is enough to break the visual block insert that repeats the insertion on every line of the block, probably because the insertion is meant to happen on a specific column, but the change of indentation messes up with the column where text in inserted in the first line, so Vim probably just gives up and keeps the insertion to that line alone.

The reason why this issue doesn't happen in `vim -u NONE` is that, even though `'indentkeys'` includes `0#` in that case (it's part of the default), the `'indentexpr'` option isn't set in that case, and `'indentkeys'` only does something when `'indentexpr'` is set. (You can easily reproduce this issue under `vim -u NONE` by using `:set indentexpr=0`.)

The reason why this issue doesn't happen in a Python script is that the ftplugin for `python` [explicitly removes `0#` from `'indentkeys'`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim#L15). (You could argue that the ftplugin for `cmake` should do the same, since both languages use `#` to mark comments.)

The workaround I would recommend is that you add an ftplugin script for `cmake` that will remove `0#` from `'indentkeys'`.

You can do so by creating a file `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/cmake.vim` (that's on NeoVim, or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cmake.vim` on Vim for Linux/Unix, or `%HOME%\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\cmake.vim` on Vim for Windows), with the following command in it:

```
setlocal indentkeys-=0#
```

This file will be loaded after the ftplugin from Vim runtimes is loaded and will update `'indentkeys'` to remove the setting that is breaking your particular use case.

Comment: wow, that ended up way more complex than I expected. Thanks for the answer and background explanation!

Comment: @ryan0270 Ditto! I was expecting this was going to be a rogue plug-in. Surprised me that this was actually behavior of the option defaults and stock runtime. (BTW, I think this should be fixed upstream, I'll try to send a pull request to have the default `cmake.vim` drop `0#` from `'indentkeys'` since that seems to make sense there.) Cheers!